# Adding Several User_id's into a Call Form Rails 4 Ruby 2

Tags: html, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am building out a dispatch app. Using Rails 4 Ruby 2

I would like a user when filling out a call form to be able to add up to 4 other users to the call they are creating. (form ect. Will be displayed below) I have created a Join Table and both the User and Call models have been updated with a has_and_belongs_to_many association. This is where I get really weak. I am not sure how to add each additional user to the form as the call model only references one user_id so as the form stands now, even if I select 4 separate users it only displays one user in all 4 user boxes. How can I make it so that each additional unit added to the call either from an update or from create will be added? and then how do I transfer that into the index.html.erb and show.html.erb views?

**My Form Looks Like:**

```
<%= @form_for(@call) do |f| %>
<div class="panel panel-success" id="responding-box">
      <div class="panel-heading"><center><h4>Units Responding</h4></center></div>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><center>Unit #1</center></th>
            <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
            <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><center><%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit_on_scene %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit_clear %></center></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><center>Unit #2</center></th>
            <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
            <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><center><%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit2_os %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit2_cl %></center></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><center>Unit #3</center></th>
            <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
            <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><center><%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit3_os %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit3_cl %></center></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><center>Unit #4</center></th>
            <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
            <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td><center><%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %></center></td> 
            <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit4_os %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit4_cl %></center></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**My Join Table looks like:**

```
 create_table "calls_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "call_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  add_index "calls_users", ["call_id"], name: "index_calls_users_on_call_id", using: :btree
  add_index "calls_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_calls_users_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

My Call.rb Model looks like:

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to_many :users

end
```

My User.rb Model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  #  and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :calls
end
```

and my Calls Controller looks like:

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_call, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /calls
  # GET /calls.json
  def index
    @calls = Call.all
    @active_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'ACTIVE'}
    @pending_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'PENDING'}
  end

  # GET /calls/1
  # GET /calls/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /calls/new
  def new
    @call = Call.new
  end

  # GET /calls/1/edit
  def edit
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /calls
  # POST /calls.json
  def create
    @call = Call.new(call_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.save
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1
  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update(call_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /calls/1
  # DELETE /calls/1.json
  def destroy
    @call.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calls_url, notice: 'Call was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_call
      @call = Call.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def call_params
      params.require(:call).permit(:call_time, :status, :primary_type, :secondary_type, :site, :address, :unit_1, :unit_2, :unit_3, :unit_4, :call_details, :unit_on_scene, :unit_clear, :call_num, :site_id, :user_id, :unit2_os, :unit2_cl, :unit3_os, :unit3_cl, :unit4_os, :unit4_cl)
    end
end
```

I am jacked up on this and can't proceed until I get this sorted out! Please any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem. This will help you to accomplish what you want!

Comment: Thats an excellent little gem there! thanks for pointing it out!